# Using eval function to create driver object in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to use eval function to create a driver object in selenium. But am getting an error - "ReferenceError: "FirefoxDriver" is not defined". At line - "Object objBrow = objJSEngine.eval(strTxt);"

As I want to put the string -driver type in property file eventually. Below is the code.
Could anyone help me on this. Thanks.

```
package septmeber;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Initial {

public static void main(String arrParm[]) throws ScriptException
{
    //Declare Variables
    String strClassName;
    By objBYTwiter;
    WebElement objTwitterTag;
    String strBorwserType;
    String strTxt;
    String strURL;

    objBYTwiter = null;
    objTwitterTag = null;
    strClassName = "span[class = 'at16nc at300bs at15nc at15t_twitter at16t_twitter']";
    strBorwserType = "FirefoxDriver"; 
    strURL = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_enumeration_interface.htm";

     //Create Driver object
    ScriptEngineManager objManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine objJSEngine = objManager.getEngineByName("js");     
    strTxt = "new"+"\t "+strBorwserType+"();" ;
    Object objBrow = objJSEngine.eval(strTxt);
    WebDriver objBrowser = (WebDriver)objBrow;

    //Launch the application
    objBrowser.get(strURL);
    objBrowser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    System.out.println("Application launched");
    objBrowser.manage().window().maximize();

    //Click Twitter Link
    objBYTwiter = By.cssSelector(strClassName);
    objTwitterTag = objBrowser.findElement(objBYTwiter);
    objTwitterTag.click();      

    }
```

}

Comment: `ScriptEngineManager` has absolutely nothing to do with Selenium, so this is why you are getting these errors. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: To evaluate a expression (lik - 3*5+5 or x = y) at run time, we can use the eval function available in ScriptEngineManager. My question is can we use the same concept to create objects at run time?

Comment: That is Instaed of creating object like this -
    new FireFoxDriver();
Can we do like this  - 
    obj.eva("new"+"/t"+"FireFoxDriver"+"();")

So that  I can replace the driver name at run time by concatenating a variable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium, this is problem with your understanding of Java!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible.

You can create a method something like:

```
WebDriver selenium;

public void setSelenium(String driver) {

    if (driver.equals("firefox")) {
        selenium = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (driver.equals("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chrome");
        selenium = new ChromeDriver();
    }   // define more as you need
}
```

Then you can call this method with something like:

```
setSelenium(System.getenv("browser"));
```

Where in your environment you first set the variable "browser" to whichever you want to run. You can also get this value from something else, like a file.